# Задача по вложенным циклам

Tags: java

Всем привет!
Понимаю, что задача простая, но не могу разобраться с решением.
Нужно с помощью двух вложенных циклов вывести все целые положительные числа произведение которых будет равно значению `value`в таком формате:

```
1*6
2*3 
и т.д.
```

Проблема в том, что и `ì` и `j` выводятся по несколько раз.

```
        System.out.println("Введите число");
        int value = 6; //new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();


        for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
            if (value % i != 0) continue;


            for (int j = value; j >= 1 ; j--) {
                if (value % j != 0) continue;
                System.out.println(i + "*" + j);
            }
        }
```

[image: Результат выполнения]

Comment: Зачем тут два цикла? Если у вас число i, то второе число это j=value/i

Comment: Да, понимаю, так гораздо элегантнее, но нужно решить двумя вложенными циклами

Comment: `произведение которых будет равно значению value` проверяется так: `if (value == i * j)   System.out.println(i + "*" + j);`

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось вот так:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    int n;

    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int value = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

    for (i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
        for (n = 1; n <= value; n++) {
            if (i * n == value){
                System.out.println(i + "*" + n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Выводит все 4 правильных исхода получения числа